# Terraform syntax error when using google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I got the error when I use the terraform in cloud shell(google cloud)
Terraform version is v1.1.7
It says

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

│   on main.tf line 75, in resource "google_compute_backend_service" "gke":
│   75:     group = replace(element(google_container_cluster.default.instance_group_urls, 1), "Manager","")
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "instance_group_urls".
```

Probably a years ago, it works properly in same tf file.
I did not remember which terraform version I use in that time.
How I modify the file in this terraform version??

Below the one of the content tf file.
75 line is from "group"  to "Manager","")

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "gke" {
  name          = "gke-demo-backend-gke"
  port_name     = "port-test"
  protocol      = "HTTP"
  timeout_sec   = 10
  enable_cdn    = false
  backend {
    group = replace(element(google_container_cluster.default.instance_group_urls, 1), "Manager","")
 }
  health_checks = [google_compute_http_health_check.default.self_link]
}
```

Your cooperation would be highly appreciated!!

How I modify the file in this terraform version??

Comment: The error is in this resource: `google_container_cluster`. It says there is no such attribute for `instance_group_urls` that is being exported: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster. Also, this usually has nothing to do with Terraform version, rather with the **provider** version.

Comment: @Marko E Thanx you for your explanation!  I understand the Terraform version is irrelevant, and it related with hashicorp provider version. To work this tf file, I need to fix the attribute the URL you sent me. Is that my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't know, since that resource is missing from your question I cannot tell for sure which attribute needs to be used, but as far as I know from the documentation, it seems there is no such attribute.